# python locals() and loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something very simple, I don't know why I can't solve this...

I have 2 arguments, I just want to put them both into a list by using a loop, the reason I'm using a loop is because one day the function may take many sys.argv instead of locals, here's what I mean:

```
def function(arg1, arg2):
    list = []
    for i in range(len(locals())):
        list.append(locals()[i])
function(1,2)
```

If you understand what I mean, can you please show me a solution to this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`locals()` is a dict, just use `.values()` to get all the containd values:

```
list = locals().values()
```

However, if your function will in the future use `sys.argv`, make your function use positional arguments instead:

```
def func(*args):
    # args is a list of arguments
    print args

func(1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you'd need to use `locals()` for the purpose of getting values from `sys.argv`?  If you're parsing command line arguments, maybe look into `argparse`?
http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html